# I have set my animation to play when the player enters a set area a through script but it's not playing

Tags: unity, animation

I have set my animation to play through a script I made but it's not playing. I have all the references correct my spelling is correct as well.
My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator myDoor;
    [SerializeField] private string DoorOpen = "DoorOpen";

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            myDoor.Play(DoorOpen, 0, 0.0f);
            Debug.Log("Animation Played");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Picture of my animator window:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Animator.Play](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html).

> When you specify a state name, or the string used to generate a hash, **it should include the name of the parent layer**. For example, if you have a Bounce state in the Base Layer, the name is Base Layer.Bounce.

So try this:

```
[SerializeField] private string DoorOpen = "Base Layer.DoorOpen";
```

*Playing the animation directly is not recommended, you can try to control the parameters to let the animation state machine control the animation playing.